# Skill cooldown animation effect similar to games like WoW in css/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to make an effect where when a skill icon is clicked, it goes on "cooldown" similar to when a skill goes on cooldown in a typical MMO like WoW.

I found the below code for achieving such an effect, but it's not documented and I don't very much understand it but want to make changes to it.

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="skill"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="skill"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="skill"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="skill"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="skill"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.skill {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #36393E;
    border-radius: 5%;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("skill.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.cooldown {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

js:

```
function cooldown(container, percent) {
    var div = $(container);
    div.empty();
    
    var total = 100;
    if(percent < total) {
        var data = [percent, total - percent];
        var width = div.width();
        var height = div.height();
        var cx = width / 2;
        var cy = height / 2;
        var r = cx * Math.SQRT2;
        var colors = [null, '#AAA'];
        var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        var chart = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg:svg");
        chart.setAttribute("width", width);
        chart.setAttribute("height", height);
        chart.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
        
        var angles = []
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) angles[i] = data[i] / total * Math.PI * 2;
        startangle = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var endangle = startangle + angles[i];
            
            var x1 = cx + r * Math.sin(startangle);
            var y1 = cy - r * Math.cos(startangle);
            var x2 = cx + r * Math.sin(endangle);
            var y2 = cy - r * Math.cos(endangle);
            
            var big = 0;
            if (endangle - startangle > Math.PI) big = 1;
            
            var path = document.createElementNS(svgns, "path");
            
            var d = "M " + cx + "," + cy + " L " + x1 + "," + y1 +
                " A " + r + "," + r + " 0 " + big + " 1 " +
                x2 + "," + y2 + " Z";
            
            path.setAttribute("d", d);
            if(colors[i]) {
                path.setAttribute("fill", colors[i]);
            } else {
                path.setAttribute("opacity", 0);
            }
            chart.appendChild(path);
            startangle = endangle;
        }   
        
        chart.setAttribute('overflow', 'hidden');
        div.append(chart);
    }
}

$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.skill').each(function() {
        var skill = $(this);
        var div = $('<div />').appendTo(skill).addClass('cooldown');
        var radius = div.parent().width() / 2;
        
        skill.click(function() {
            $({pct: 0}).animate({pct: 100}, {
                duration: 5000,
                step: function (curLeft) { cooldown(div, curLeft); }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I managed to make one change to it that I wanted which was to add text with the cooldown time, like so: (haven't done updating of it in js yet but I think that's something I can do myself)

```
<div class="skill"><div class="text">5</div></div>

.skill .text {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #E1E5EB;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    line-height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

The other changes that I need help with are:

- Filling counter-clockwise instead of clockwise.
- Flip the opacity of filled/unfilled portions (currently the
  filled portion is dark and unfilled is light but I want the opposite)

Comment: Flipping opacity sounds like it would just require putting the `opacity: 0.8;` in the `.skill` CSS ruleset (thus making 0.8 the default) and putting `opacity 1` in the `.cooldown` ruleset (since 1 means complete opacity.)
And filling counter-clockwise might involve changing `for(...){ angles[i] = ...}` to `for(...){ angles[data.length - i] = ...}`

Comment: I've actually managed to get that working the way I wanted. I flipped the color array in the js `var colors = ['#AAA', null];` and added `background-color: transparent;` to cooldown in the css. Now I just need to figure out how to invert the filling direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach would be to use the [conic-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient()) together with some [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). This way we don't need to build an SVG.

PS: There are comments in the JS to explain how it works.

```js
const SECOND_IN_MS = 1000;
const UPDATE_INTERVAL = SECOND_IN_MS / 60; // Update 60 times per second (60 FPS)
const SKILL_CLASS = 'skill';
const DISABLED_CLASS = 'disabled';

// Cooldowns per skill in milliseconds
const COOLDOWN_MAP = new Map([
  ['run', 1000],
  ['jump', 2000],
  ['crawl', 3000],
  ['slide', 4000],
  ['tumble', 5000],
]);

// Get skills table from the DOM
const skillsTable = document.querySelector('.skills-table');

// Activate clicked skill
const activateSkill = (event) => {
  const {target} = event;
  
  // Exit if we click on anything that isn't a skill
  if(!target.classList.contains(SKILL_CLASS)) return;
  
  target.classList.add(DISABLED_CLASS);
  target.style = '--time-left: 100%';
  
  // Get cooldown time
  const skill = target.dataset.skill;
  let time = COOLDOWN_MAP.get(skill) - UPDATE_INTERVAL;
  
  // Update remaining cooldown
  const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    // Pass remaining time in percentage to CSS
    const passedTime = time / COOLDOWN_MAP.get(skill) * 100;
    target.style = `--time-left: ${passedTime}%`;
    
    // Display time left
    target.textContent = (time / SECOND_IN_MS).toFixed(2);
    time -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
    
    // Stop timer when there is no time left
    if(time < 0) {
      target.textContent = '';
      target.style = '';
      target.classList.remove(DISABLED_CLASS);
      
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
  }, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}

// Add click handler to the table
skillsTable.addEventListener('click', activateSkill, false);
```

```css
.skill {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #36393E;
  border-radius: 5%;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Prevents you from clicked the button multiple times */
.skill.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Makes sure we click the skill not anything in it */
.skill > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.skill::before {
  content: "";
  background: conic-gradient(
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) var(--time-left),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) var(--time-left));
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 0;
  left: 0p;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class='skills-table'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- data-skill refers to the COOLDOWN_MAP in JS -->
      <div class="skill" data-skill='run'></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- data-skill refers to the COOLDOWN_MAP in JS -->
      <div class="skill" data-skill='jump'></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- data-skill refers to the COOLDOWN_MAP in JS -->
      <div class="skill" data-skill='crawl'></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- data-skill refers to the COOLDOWN_MAP in JS -->
      <div class="skill" data-skill='slide'></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- data-skill refers to the COOLDOWN_MAP in JS -->
      <div class="skill" data-skill='tumble'></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the CSS I used for a cleaner look (change the border-radius to your button's border radius minus half the border width to make it clean): `.skill::before { position: absolute; background: conic-gradient(#000b var(--time-left), transparent var(--time-left)); border-radius: 8px; opacity: 0.8; content: ""; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }`