# How to create a spinning loading overlay like in RPG game in CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create spinning loading overlay like in RPG games for the character skills. Here is an example from WoW (I need exactly like this);

[image: Skill loadin overlay]

This is my attempt (turns out my CSS skills are not that powerful) - as you can see it has weird look.

[image]

Any ideas on how to do it, thanks!

Source in ClojureScript, but should not be problem I guess;

```
(def skill-keyframes-opa
  ((keyframes (j/lit {"0%" {:opacity "1"}
                      "50%, 100%" {:opacity "0"}}))))

(def skill-loading-wrapper
  (css (j/lit {:background :white
               :opacity 0.5
               :z-index 1
               :width 45
               :height 45
               :position :relative
               :top 2
               :left 2})))

(def skill-loading-pie
  (css (j/lit {:width "50%"
               :height "100%"
               :position :absolute
               :transform-origin "100% 50%"
               :background :grey
               :border "10px solid rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.4)"})))

(defn- skill-loading-spinner [duration]
  ((css (j/lit {:border-radius "100% 0 0 100% / 50% 0 0 50%"
                :z-index 200
                :border-right :none
                :animation (str skill-keyframes-rota " " duration "s linear infinite")}))))

(defn- skill-loading-filler [duration]
  ((css (j/lit {:border-radius "0 100% 100% 0 / 0 50% 50% 0"
                :z-index 100
                :border-left :none
                :animation (str skill-keyframes-opa " " duration "s steps(1, end) infinite reverse")
                :left "50%"
                :opacity 0}))))

(defn skill-loading-mask [duration]
  ((css (j/lit {:width "50%"
                :height "100%"
                :position :absolute
                :z-index 300
                :opacity 1
                :background :inherit
                :animation (str skill-keyframes-opa " " duration "s steps(1, end) infinite")}))))

(defn use-skill [duration]
  [:div {:class (skill-loading-wrapper)}
   [:div {:class [(skill-loading-pie) (skill-loading-spinner duration)]}]
   [:div {:class [(skill-loading-pie) (skill-loading-filler duration)]}]
   [:div {:class (skill-loading-mask duration)}]])
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @FiddlingAway posted now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67261754/skill-cooldown-animation-effect-similar-to-games-like-wow-in-css-js/67262631#67262631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property

@property animation should be replaced with `style.setProperty('--cooldown', '23.4%')` js animation as js values are source of truth

```css
.cooldown {
  /* set via style.setProperty('--cooldown', '23.4%') in js */
  --cooldown: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(
      transparent 0,
      transparent var(--cooldown),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) var(--cooldown),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  );
  animation: cooldown 1s linear infinite;
}

/* makes --cooldown animateable for css animations */
@property --cooldown {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0%;
}

@keyframes cooldown {
  0% { --cooldown: 0%; }
  100% { --cooldown: 100%; }
}

/* makes children be over each other */
.childs-overlayed {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "only";
}
.childs-overlayed > * {
  grid-area: only;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="childs-overlayed">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <div class="cooldown"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can simplify `background: conic-gradient(transparent var(--cooldown), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) var(--cooldown));`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make the overlay on the left dark instead of light. The weirdness probably comes from the perception that the lighter overlay is actually "on top" of the darker icon.

If you instead use a dark (or even black) overlay, it will match the example more closely.